# nginx doesn't serve static assets in Rails 4.1.8 + Spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, unicorn

I have a problem with Nginx - Unicorn - Rails 4.1 and Spree *production* setup, according to [this tutorial](https://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/manual-ubuntu.html#setting-up-a-web-server).

The site shows up at the ip address (I need to get a domain yet). But it seems assets are not readable. This is the error log from */var/log/nginx/spree_zaza_error.log*

```
2014/12/21 23:06:22 [error] 13598#0: *12 open() "/home/user/workplace/spree_zaza/public/assets/spree.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 213.230.83.135, server: , request: "GET /assets/spree.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1", host: "212.111.40.25", referrer: "http://212.111.40.25/t/brand/apache"
2014/12/21 23:06:22 [error] 13598#0: *11 open() "/home/user/workplace/spree_zaza/public/assets/spree/frontend/checkout.js" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 213.230.83.135, server: , request: "GET /assets/spree/frontend/checkout.js?body=1 HTTP/1.1", host: "212.111.40.25", referrer: "http://212.111.40.25/t/brand/apache"
2014/12/21 23:06:22 [error] 13598#0: *11 open() "/home/user/workplace/spree_zaza/public/assets/logo/spree_50.png" failed (2: No such file or directory), client: 213.230.83.135, server: , request: "GET /assets/logo/spree_50.png HTTP/1.1", host: "212.111.40.25", referrer: "http://212.111.40.25/t/brand/apache"
```

Although I ran `rake assets:precompile` and there are a bunch of hashed and gzipped files, some files don't exist, but for example assests/logo/spree_50 is there.

This is my */etc/nginx/sites-enabled/spree_zaza* file:

```
upstream spree_zaza {
  # fail_timeout=0 means we always retry an upstream even if it failed
  # to return a good HTTP response (in case the Unicorn master nukes a
  # single worker for timing out).
  server unix:/tmp/spree_zaza.socket fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  # if you're running multiple servers, instead of "default" you should
  # put your main domain name here
  listen 80 default;

  # you could put a list of other domain names this application answers
  #server_name [your server's address];

  root /home/user/workplace/spree_zaza/public;
  access_log /var/log/nginx/spree_zaza_access.log;
  error_log /var/log/nginx/spree_zaza_error.log;
  rewrite_log on;

  location / {
    #all requests are sent to the UNIX socket
    proxy_pass http://spree_zaza;
    proxy_redirect off;

    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;

    client_max_body_size 10m;
    client_body_buffer_size 128k;

    proxy_connect_timeout 90;
    proxy_send_timeout 90;
    proxy_read_timeout 90;

    proxy_buffer_size 4k;
    proxy_buffers 4 32k;
    proxy_busy_buffers_size 64k;
    proxy_temp_file_write_size 64k;
  }

  # if the request is for a static resource, nginx should serve it directly
  # and add a far future expires header to it, making the browser
  # cache the resource and navigate faster over the website
  location ~ ^/(system|assets|spree)/  {
    root /home/user/workplace/spree_zaza/public;
    expires max;
    break;
  }
}
```

And the following is */home/user/workplace/spree_zaza/config/unicorn.rb*:

```
# config/unicorn.rb
# Set environment to development unless something else is specified
#env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "development"
#env = ENV["RAILS_ENV"] || "production"
env = "production"

# See http://unicorn.bogomips.org/Unicorn/Configurator.html for complete documentation.
worker_processes 3

# listen on both a Unix domain socket and a TCP port, 
# we use a shorter backlog for quicker failover when busy
listen "/tmp/spree_zaza.socket", backlog: 64

# Preload our app for more speed
preload_app true

# nuke workers after 30 seconds instead of 60 seconds (the default)
timeout 30

pid "/tmp/unicorn.spree_zaza.pid"

# Production specific settings
if env == "production"
  # Help ensure your application will always spawn in the symlinked
  # "current" directory that Capistrano sets up.
  working_directory "/home/user/workplace/spree_zaza"

  # feel free to point this anywhere accessible on the filesystem user 'spree'
  shared_path = "/home/user/workplace/spree_zaza"

  stderr_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stderr.log"
  stdout_path "#{shared_path}/log/unicorn.stdout.log"
end

before_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is highly recomended for Rails + "preload_app true"
  # as there's no need for the master process to hold a connection
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.disconnect!
  end

  # Before forking, kill the master process that belongs to the .oldbin PID.
  # This enables 0 downtime deploys.
  old_pid = "/tmp/unicorn.spree_zaza.pid.oldbin"
  if File.exists?(old_pid) && server.pid != old_pid
    begin
      Process.kill("QUIT", File.read(old_pid).to_i)
    rescue Errno::ENOENT, Errno::ESRCH
      # someone else did our job for us
    end
  end
end

after_fork do |server, worker|
  # the following is *required* for Rails + "preload_app true"
  if defined?(ActiveRecord::Base)
    ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
  end

  # if preload_app is true, then you may also want to check and
  # restart any other shared sockets/descriptors such as Memcached,
  # and Redis.  TokyoCabinet file handles are safe to reuse
  # between any number of forked children (assuming your kernel
  # correctly implements pread()/pwrite() system calls)
end
```

Also, I uncommented the following switch in config/environments/production.rb

```
config.action_dispatch.x_sendfile_header = 'X-Accel-Redirect'
```

Thanks for your ideas.